# flattening a dataframe inside a data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

i have a data.table with the following characteristics

```
> print(wb_failures_summary)
            V1        codes       enodeb         IMSI
 1:       BACT <data.frame> <data.frame> <data.frame>
 2:    BREERAB <data.frame> <data.frame> <data.frame>
 3:     DETACH <data.frame> <data.frame> <data.frame>
 4:     ATTACH <data.frame> <data.frame> <data.frame>
 5: MMPAGEHIGH <data.frame> <data.frame> <data.frame>
 6:     SVCREQ <data.frame> <data.frame> <data.frame>
 7:         HO <data.frame> <data.frame> <data.frame>
 8:        BHO <data.frame> <data.frame> <data.frame>
 9:    PAGEMED <data.frame> <data.frame> <data.frame>
10:         NA <data.frame> <data.frame> <data.frame>
11:        TAU <data.frame> <data.frame> <data.frame>
12:    PAGELCS <data.frame> <data.frame> <data.frame>
13:       BMOD <data.frame> <data.frame> <data.frame>
14:      BPRSV <data.frame> <data.frame> <data.frame>
```

> the data.frame variables in the data.table object are as follows

```
> print(wb_failures_summary[1]$codes)
[[1]]
            x   Freq
36 006B000000 437962
7  000906001A   8117
24 0023000000    992
22 002006001A    872
10 0009060023    819
35 0069000000    450
1  0005000000    433
14 000A05002C    319
33 0057000000    178
25 0024000000    167

>
```

i need the codes, enodeb,imsi to be looking like named list as follows e.g for codes i would like them to appear as below

c("006B000000"= "437962","000906001A"="8117"....)

i guess i need to flatten the data.frame duly to do so... not able to figure how .
pointers will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

finally..did manage to solve...
a simple paste was what necessary...
the final code

```
frequency_of_data <- function(x){
  t<-table(x)
  t<-as.data.frame(t,stringAsFactors=FALSE)
  t<-t[order(-t$Freq),]
  t<-t[1:10,]
  **t1<-paste(t$x,"=",t$Freq)**
  t1
}
wb_failures_summary <- wb_failures_errorcode[,.(codes=.(frequency_of_data(code)),enodeb=.(frequency_of_data(V16)),IMSI=.(frequency_of_data(V2)),APN=.(frequency_of_data(V58)),QCI=.(frequency_of_data(V57))),by=V1]
```

---the final o/p----

```
> wb_failures_summary
            V1                                                                                                            codes
 1:       BACT       006B000000 = 437962,000906001A = 8117,0023000000 = 992,002006001A = 872,0009060023 = 819,0069000000 = 450,
 2:    BREERAB 002C000000 = 679672,0057000000 = 98492,000906001A = 61815,0024000000 = 9614,00090A0004 = 8426,0023000000 = 5514,
 3:     DETACH                0018000000 = 5130,004C000000 = 514,004F000000 = 73,003C000000 = 36,001F000000 = 4,0024000000 = 1,
 4:     ATTACH       008006001A = 5328,0036000000 = 4927,0018000000 = 3689,007D000000 = 1139,004C06001A = 399,0038000000 = 381,
 5: MMPAGEHIGH                                                                = 100088,NA = NA,NA = NA,NA = NA,NA = NA,NA = NA,
 6:     SVCREQ    008006001A = 35198,00BE000000 = 8893,00800A0004 = 4523,00BD000000 = 3958,003E000000 = 1626,004F000000 = 1200,
 7:         HO           0032000000 = 4458,0050000000 = 742,004C060006 = 448,004F000000 = 347,007C000000 = 166,000D000000 = 41,
 8:        BHO                                                                  = 3046,NA = NA,NA = NA,NA = NA,NA = NA,NA = NA,
 9:    PAGEMED                                                                   = 332,NA = NA,NA = NA,NA = NA,NA = NA,NA = NA,
10:         NA                                                                = 318082,NA = NA,NA = NA,NA = NA,NA = NA,NA = NA,
11:        TAU        005A000000 = 11075,003E000000 = 1998,004D000000 = 1631,0038000000 = 903,0019000000 = 253,004F000000 = 39,
12:    PAGELCS                                                                   = 593,NA = NA,NA = NA,NA = NA,NA = NA,NA = NA,
13:       BMOD                   000906001A = 41,000A05002C = 35,0020060000 = 22,0009060023 = 13,0005000000 = 5,0027000000 = 5,
14:      BPRSV                                                         0027000000 = 23,NA = NA,NA = NA,NA = NA,NA = NA,NA = NA,
```

rajib